# FFMPEG 5 AVStream.cur_dts is removed

Tags: ffmpeg

In the ffmpeg 5+, i noticed that the field cur_dts in AVStream is removed, anyone knows whats the alternative way?

Currently I am using the below code to generate video:

```
        if (packet->dts <= stream->cur_dts) {
        logD(RECORDER_TAG, "DTS not increasing, packet.dts:%d, cur:%d.", packet->dts,
             stream->cur_dts);
        ret = 0;
        av_packet_unref(packet);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to update history of FFmpeg/libavformat/avformat.h

This was a private field. You are not supposed to use it outside of FFmpeg code and they moved it to "internal" to prevent people using it.

> Commits on Jun 9, 2021: avformat: move AVStream.{first,cur}_dts to
> AVStreamInternal
>
> They are private fields, no reason to have them exposed in a public
> header.

Here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/591b88e6787c4e678237f02a50421d101abd25c2

Comment: thank you for your reply. i think that means I should not use this field.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is some other way you need to check.